# OCR Document Scanning .NET SDK

Tags: .net, sdk, ocr

Does anyone have any positive/negative feedback on a .NET SDK for document scanning. Not sure where to start when comparing, and would love a human opinion! TIA!

Comment: I assume you want to scan a document and then do OCR on it? If you consider commercial products, there are several options: Dynamsoft Dynamic .NET TWAIN and its OCR add-on, Leadtools Document Imaging and OCR module, Atalasoft DotImage and its OCR add-on.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there are a number of options out there depending on how you want to implement them.  Tessnet2 is a good option:

http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/

As is MODI (Microsoft Office Document Imaging library) if you have Microsoft Office already:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/modi.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many OCR engines available:
[List of most popular engines.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_character_recognition_software)
It completely depends on your task. For our task we got poor results with Tesseract and good results with CrystalOCR. I think the best OCR is ABBYY, though their license policy was not acceptable for us.